# Updating child record while updating parent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, controller

I have a model of a "shipment" and a child model of that "`shipment_details`", I have created an edit form where if I go to edit the overall shipment, I would like the ability to make updates to the `shipment_details` as well.

At the moment, here is my "shipment" model:

```
public function shipment_details(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Shipment_Detail', 'shipment_id','pro_number');
}
```

And here is my controller for my edit page update:

```
public function updateRecord(Request $request, $id)
    {

      $shipment = Shipment::where('UUID','=',$id)->firstOrFail();

        //Save Initial Shipment Data
        $shipment->pro_number = request('pro_number');
        $shipment->shipment_origin = request('shipment_origin');
        $shipment->date = request('date');
        $shipment->due_date = request('due_date');
        $shipment->tractor_id = request('tractor_id');
        $shipment->trailer_id = request('trailer_id');
        $shipment->driver_id = request('driver_id');
        $shipment->notes = request('notes');
        $shipment->shipper_no = request('shipper_no');
        $shipment->ship_to = request('ship_to');
        $shipment->ship_from = request('ship_from');
        $shipment->bill_to = request('bill_to');
        $shipment->bill_type = request('bill_type');
        $shipment->load_date = request('load_date');
        $shipment->shipment_status = 1;
        $shipment->shipment_billing_status = (isset($request->shipment_billing_status) && !empty($request->shipment_billing_status)) ? $request->shipment_billing_status : 1;
        $shipment->cn_billtoName = request('cn_billtoName');
        $shipment->cn_billtoAddress1 = request('cn_billtoAddress1');
        $shipment->cn_billtoAddress2 = request('cn_billtoAddress2');
        $shipment->cn_billtoCity = request('cn_billtoCity');
        $shipment->cn_billtoState = request('cn_billtoState');
        $shipment->cn_billtoZip = request('cn_billtoZip');
        $shipment->cn_billtoEmail = request('cn_billtoEmail');
        $shipment->cn_billtoPhone = request('cn_billtoPhone');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoName = request('cn_shiptoName');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoAddress1 = request('cn_shiptoAddress1');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoAddress2 = request('cn_shiptoAddress2');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoCity = request('cn_shiptoCity');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoState = request('cn_shiptoState');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoZip = request('cn_shiptoZip');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoEmail = request('cn_shiptoEmail');
        $shipment->cn_shiptoPhone = request('cn_shiptoPhone');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromName = request('cn_shipfromName');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromAddress1 = request('cn_shipfromAddress1');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromAddress2 = request('cn_shipfromAddress2');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromCity = request('cn_shipfromCity');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromState = request('cn_shipfromState');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromZip = request('cn_shipfromZip');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromEmail = request('cn_shipfromEmail');
        $shipment->cn_shipfromPhone = request('cn_shipfromPhone');
        $shipment->fuelChargeDesc = request('fuelChargeDesc');
        $shipment->fuelChargeAmt = request('fuelChargeAmt');
        $shipment->fuelChargeTotal = request('fuelChargeTotal');
        $shipment->permitChargeDesc = request('permitChargeDesc');
        $shipment->permitChargeAmt = request('permitChargeAmt');
        $shipment->permitChargeTotal = request('permitChargeTotal');
        $shipment->otherChargeDesc = request('otherChargeDesc');
        $shipment->otherChargeAmt = request('otherChargeAmt');
        $shipment->otherChargeTotal = request('otherChargeTotal');
        $shipment->noCharge = request('noCharge');
        $shipment->noSettle = request('noSettle');
        $shipment->Total = request('Total');
        if ((request('shipment_billing_status') == 2) || (request('shipment_billing_status') == 3)){
           $balance = 0.00;
        }else{
           $balance = request('Total');
        }
        $shipment->Balance = $balance;
        $shipment->freightBillSubtotal = request('freightBillSubtotal');

        $shipment->save();

        //Save Shipment Details -- NEED HELP HERE //

           for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->shipment_details['piecesNumber']); $i++) {

            $Shipment_Detail = Shipment_Detail::where
            Shipment_Detail::create([
                'shipment_id' => $shipment->pro_number,
                'pieces_number' => $request->shipment_details['piecesNumber'][$i],
                'pieces_type' => $request->shipment_details['piecesType'][$i],
                'rate_type' => $request->shipment_details['rateType'][$i],
                'charge' => $request->shipment_details['charge'][$i],
                'weight' => $request->shipment_details['weight'][$i],
                'hazmat' => $request->shipment_details['hazmat'][$i],
                'description' => $request->shipment_details['description'][$i] ]);
        }

        //END HELP HERE SECTION//


        Session::flash('success_message','Freight Bill Successfully Updated'); //<--FLASH MESSAGE

        //Return to Register//
        return redirect('/shipments/i/'.$shipment->UUID);

    }
```

Near to the bottom, you can see the section where I have marked out the portion where I need help with. The code that is there is partially taken from my create page for my shipments to store, and it works well. I assumed I could use it in this case, but I'm not sure how I would about identifying the `shipment_details` to update and how I would pass that along to be updated in the `shipment_details` database table records.

This is my html specific to the `shipment_details` associated with the shipment that is being updated:

```
  <tbody>
                    @foreach($shipment_details as $sd)
                        <tr style="height:40px">
                            <td style="width:8%;text-align:center;">{{Form::text('shipment_details[piecesNumber][]', $sd->pieces_number, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'No. Pieces','required','id'=>'piecesNumber'))}}
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16%;text-align:center;">
                            {!! Form::select('shipment_details[piecesType][]', $piecetypes, $sd->pieces_type, ['id' => 'pieces_type', 'class' => 'form-control full-width','required']) !!}    
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            {!! Form::select('shipment_details[rateType][]', $ratetypes, $sd->rate_type, ['id' => 'rateType', 'class' => 'form-control full-width','required']) !!}
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
                            {{Form::text('shipment_details[weight][]', $sd->weight, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Weight','required','id'=>'weight'))}}    
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
                             {{Form::select('shipment_details[hazmat][]',array(
                                    'No'=>'No',
                                    'Yes'=>'Yes',
                                ), $sd->hazmat, array('class' => 'form-control','id'=>'hazmat'))}}   
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
                            {{Form::text('shipment_details[description][]', $sd->description, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Description','required','id'=>'description'))}} 
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
                            {{Form::text('shipment_details[charge][]', $sd->charge, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Charge','required','id'=>'charge'))}} 
                            </td>
                            <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                </tr> 
                    @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

And the `shipment_details` are pulled to the page through the controller using this:

```
$shipment_details = $shipment->shipment_details;
```

### Update in response to answer

I am now using the following to save details in my `shipment` controller:

```
        foreach ( $request->shipment_details as $id => $details ) {
            $shipdetail = Shipment_Detail::find($id);
            $shipdetail->pieces_type = $details->piecesType;
            $shipdetail->pieces_number = $details->piecesNumber;
            $shipdetail->rate_type = $details->rateType;
            $shipdetail->weight = $details->weight;
            $shipdetail->charge = $details->charge;
            $shipdetail->description = $details->description;
            $shipdetail->hazmat = $details->hazmat;
            // Other info to update here
            $shipdetail->save();
        }
```

And my html form:

```
@foreach($shipment_details as $sd)
                        <tr style="height:40px">
                            <td style="width:8%;text-align:center;">{{Form::text('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][piecesNumber]', $sd->pieces_number, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'No. Pieces','required','id'=>'piecesNumber'))}}
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16%;text-align:center;">
                            {!! Form::select('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][piecesType]', $piecetypes, $sd->pieces_type, ['id' => 'pieces_type', 'class' => 'form-control full-width','required']) !!}    
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            {!! Form::select('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][rateType]', $ratetypes, $sd->rate_type, ['id' => 'rateType', 'class' => 'form-control full-width','required']) !!}
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
                            {{Form::text('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][weight]', $sd->weight, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Weight','required','id'=>'weight'))}}    
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
                             {{Form::select('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][hazmat]',array(
                                    'No'=>'No',
                                    'Yes'=>'Yes',
                                ), $sd->hazmat, array('class' => 'form-control','id'=>'hazmat'))}}   
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
                            {{Form::text('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][description]', $sd->description, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Description','required','id'=>'description'))}} 
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;">
                            {{Form::text('shipment_details['.$sd->id.'][charge]', $sd->charge, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Charge','required','id'=>'charge'))}} 
                            </td>
                            <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                </tr>

                    @endforeach
```

And I will mention that this array is in my error page, so I know the details are in fact being passed along:

```
shipment_billing_status     

""

shipment_details    

array:1 [▼
  13032 => array:7 [▼
    "piecesNumber" => "1"
    "piecesType" => "1"
    "rateType" => "1"
    "weight" => "454"
    "hazmat" => "No"
    "description" => "LARGE CLAM - L"
    "charge" => "65.00"
  ]
]

freightBillSubtotal     

"65.00"
```

Comment: Does the `shipment_details` record already exist and you're simply trying to update it or are you trying to create a new `shipment_details` record?

Comment: For the moment, it's just updating the `shipment_details` that already exists.

Comment: As per a note I made recently on one of your prior questions: _When composing your questions Matthew, would you make them a bit less chatty? We prefer succinct questions here. Advance thanks, notes of appreciation, signatures, and various other items (salutations, regards, hopes someone can help, deadlines, etc) tend to be trimmed, and volunteer editors are most grateful if they are not added in the first place_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the records already exist we can modify your HTML a bit to get the proper ID into the HTML to pass to your controller. Each of your existing inputs are going to need to be changed from

`{{Form::select('shipment_details[piecesType][]', ..)}}`

To

`{{Form::select('shipment_details['.$sd->id.']["piecesType"], ..)}}`

In the controller this gives us as an example:
`shipment_details[2]['piecesType'] // which equals some value`

Now, to the controller we can use:

```
foreach ( $request->shipment_details as $id => $details ) {
    $shipdetail = Shipment_Details::find($id);
    $shipdetail->piecesType = $details['piecesType'];
    // Other info to update here
    $shipdetail->save();
}
```

Which is going to replace your current `for` loop.

Comment: Alright I have implemented your suggestion but I get the following error: Trying to get property of non-object at this line: `$shipdetail->pieces_type = $details->piecesType;` -- I'll update my question with the full code I am now using so it doesn't cram this comment.

Comment: That would mean that `$shipdetail = Shipment_Details::find($id);` is returning `null`; add a check: `if($shipDetail){ ... }`.

Comment: I'll add that but I was actually testing this on one that did have a shipment_detail attached to it.

Comment: I just noticed the issue and fixed it in my answer. It was `$details->piecesType;` `$details` is an array and not an object so it should be `$details['piecesType']`. But Tim's comment is also very valid and should be done regardless to avoid throwing an error when trying `$shipdetail->someProperty`.

Comment: Ah yeah, good catch. I misread (likely due to similar variable names), but yeah, `$shipdetail`'s properties would be accessible via `->`, unless `null`, and `$details`, being an array, would need array syntax.